# How to ignore null properties in the search criteria

Tags: c#, linq

I have got a bad requirement to do; anyway I have to implement that in my application.

I have a `Track` class

```
public class Track
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

and i have some test data

```
List<Track> Records = new List<Track>
{ 
    new Track { City = "a", Name = "a",  Country = "i" }, // Track 1
    new Track { City = "b", Name = "b",  Country = "i" }, // Track 2
    new Track { City = "a", Name = null, Country = "J" }, // Track 3
    new Track { City = "c", Name = "a",  Country = "J" }, // Track 4
    new Track { City = "b", Name = "a",  Country = null}, // Track 5
};
```

Requirement is i should query the data from `Records` based on values passed. If any of the property is `null` then search criteria should ignore that property. It should query based on `NonNull` properties.

**Example**:

```
If i query for City = a, Name = "b", Country = "i" then Result is: Track 1 & Track 3
If i query for City = c, Name = "p", Country = "w" then Result is: Track 4
```

`Name` & `Country` have null values in `Track 3` & `Track 5`.So it will ignore in search. Hope it is clear

I finally land up with below logic

```
var filterRecords = new List<Track>();
if (!Records.Any(t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.City)))
{
    filterRecords = Records.Where(c => c.City == _city).ToList();  // Here _city is the method parameter.. assume "a"
}

if (!Records.Any(t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Country)))
{
    filterRecords = filterRecords.Where(c => c.City == _country).ToList();  // Here _country is the method parameter.. assume "c"
}
```

`Track` class has 12 properties. Checking for 12 times like above is not good sign.
I would like to achieve this by using `LINQ` or any other which is simple.

Any suggestions please?.

Comment: I don't understand how your queries work. They don't seem to be AND and they don't seem to be OR either.

Comment: @Adriano no, he shouldn't repeat code 12 times. See my answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're going for.  Are you saying that if *any* record has a null, then that search term is ignored?

Comment: @Bobson, Yes, Search should ignore for the property. If you are clear plesae see at lazyberezovsky post. It is great solution. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best solution came to my mind is to build aggregate filter (You can use your Track object for that, because it already has all possible properties for filtering collection, and they are nullable):

```
Track filter = records.Aggregate(
    new Track() { City = _city, Country = _country, Name = _name },
    (f, t) => new Track()
    {
        City = String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.City) ? null : f.City, 
        Country = String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Country) ? null : f.Country,
        Name = String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Name) ? null : f.Name
    },
    f => f);
```

This will require only one iteration over collection to define which fields has null. Then simply apply filter to your records:

```
var query = from t in Records
            where (filter.City == null || t.City == filter.City) &&
                    (filter.Country == null || t.Country == filter.Country) &&
                    (filter.Name == null || t.Name == filter.Name)
            select t;
```

Comment: FANTASTIC lazyberezovsky. Really great logic.. it is working fine for me. thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily chain these expressions together to create something like the following. Enumerating the records X times is going to slow down your code. Example:

```
var actualResult = Records
       .Where(x => x.City == _city || string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.City))
       .Where(x => x.Country == _country || string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Country))
       /// .... and so on
       .ToList()
```

Now, if you're looking to not just write 12 lines of code, there are more complicated solutions that involve Reflection and mapping, but that's not really needed in this situation. If your property count is huge, then maybe it might be worth it. But 12 properties is small enough that there isn't much code smell here to me.

Comment: This will not verify ANY record for containing null in property.

Comment: Each individual `Where` clause dictates the specific property must not be null or empty. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Actually, I think I understand what you mean. You want NULLs to be returned, in addition to the values that match right? In that case, you simply need an OR condition.

Comment: So, can you explain the rules here? You want an item to be returned from the collection if all of the search criteria properties match or any of those properties are null? That's probably the problem we're having here - your expected result is unclear.

Comment: @Tejs new solution still verifying only current record.

Comment: @Tej see his example `!Records.Any(t => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.Country))`. Most important part here is `Any`

Comment: So if Any record has a null property respectively, don't apply the filter? That seems backwards.

Comment: @Tejs exactly :) if any record has null for some property, we don't filter by that property

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Great explanation.. thanks for understanding my query and giving me the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding, it should be this simple:

```
var results = Records.Select(p => p.City != null && 
              p.Country != null && 
              p.Name != null).ToList();
```

Comment: your logic will return all the records.. where can i filter based on passed arguments.??

Answer (score 0):

do the quality and quantity of results returned matter to you? 
I assume you have mechanisms to handle the quantity.

You can validate your search keywords before throwing queries. Do you only care about nulls? How about redundant keywords?
I would consider:
1. validate keywords - 12 can be looped.
2. Build the search keyword strong
3. Shoot a query

Seems pretty straightforward, unless there's more to it than what you described here.

Please recorrect me, if my understanding of your question is not in the expected direction.

Comment: @Prasad : before voting me down, can you please consider the fact that I am unable to comment and trying to check with you what could be helpful to you :-(

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't voting you down.. some one else..please

Answer (score -1):

something like this

```
var listRecords = from track in Records
where (track.city == _city && !string.IsEmpyOrNull(track.city)) && 
(track.Name== _name && !string.IsEmpyOrNull(track.Name))
select track;
```

and you can add the rest of the conditions